# ActionFilterAttribute on Web api call does not correctly redirect to the new location

Tags: c#, actionfilterattribute

My action filter attribute does not redirect to the new url i have defined:

```
public class RunOnServerAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ServerType Type;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        switch (Type)
        {
            case ServerType.CMS:
                if (!filterContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(Config.CMSUrl))
                {
                    Uri correctedUri = new Uri($"{Config.CMSUrl.TrimEnd('/')}/{filterContext.Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.TrimStart('/')}");
                    var response = filterContext.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Moved);
                    response.Headers.Location = correctedUri;
                    return;
                    // This does not seem to work
                }

                break;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

It just continues on with the normal request. I am debugging this by inspecting the Request.RequestUri in the executing api method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for not noticing it's a WebAPI project.
Composing the response should be a quick resolution.

```
var res = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
res.Headers.Location = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
actionContext.Response = res;
```

------------- Updated above. --------------

You should use the filterContext.Result and assign the ActionResult. Just like what you do in normal actions.
For instance,

```
var controller = (YourBaseControllerType)filterContext.Controller;
filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName");
```

or

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(YourUrl);
```

Comment: This is not available for an API request

Comment: Should i be returning after the setting of the response. or should i then continue to run the filtercontext through the base.OnActionExecuting?

Comment: Well, it depends on your requirements. But if you just want to redirect, then not to call the base is alright.

Answer (score 0):

`OnActionExecuting` is called before controller action method invoking, so after running filter method controller action replaces response. I think method `OnActionExecuted` is better place for your code.

Comment: The Executed means it would have already run the code in the controller against the wrong api url

Comment: Do you need not return corrected url to client, but invoke another controller action in your app?